# Uniswap v3: what determines the if a tick is initialized?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, uniswapv3

Is a tick initialized if it just contains any liquidity?

If someone deposits into an uninitialized tick, are they going to initialize it? When are ticks un-initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tick is initialized (i.e. active) if it's an endpoint of a position deployed in the pool.

Only ticks that are divisible by the pool's tick spacing can be initialized. For instance, the in 0.3% pool only ticks that are divisible by 60 can be position endpoints. (In the 0.05% pools: divisible by 10; in the 1% pools: divisible by 200.)

Uninitialized ticks still may contain liquidity. For instance, most ticks in the middle of a liquidity position are uninitialized, even though they do and contain liquidity for swapping. This includes ticks that are in the middle of a position and are divisible by 60 (or 10, or 200), unless they are the endpoints of some other position.

All uninitialized ticks have `liquidityNet` and `liquidityGross` values equal to zero. (See [the v3 whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf) for the definition of these variables.) An initialized tick may have `liquidityNet` equal to zero - for example, when it's the upper tick of one position with liquidity `L`, and the lower tick of another position with the same amount of liquidity `L`, since `L - L = 0`. However, an initialized never has `liquidityGross` equal to zero. Wheneven `liquidityGross` of an active tick becomes zero dues to a position being closes, the tick is un-initialized.